How can i create a vm using a snapshot saved in Azure storage account?
I have saved a vm snapshot in Azure storage account.
I need to create a disk from this and then create a VM from the disk. The issue is that there are no options to copy the snapshot from the storage account to a resourcegroup or to create a vm .
How can i do this , if i have a snapshot in the storage account ?


How can i create a vm using a snapshot saved in Azure storage account?

Follow the steps below to create a VM using a snapshot saved in an Azure Storage account.
Create a managed disk from a snapshot stored in an Azure Storage account.
Go to Disk > Create Managed Disk > provided required details and Source Type is Storage blob >Source Blob > Browse
Make sure to pass the same OS type as the existing VM when creating the managed disk.

Select container > Select snapshot VHD  in Azure storage account.


Once you create a managed disk, you will have the option to create a VM from managed disk.

Reference: Create a managed disk from a VHD file in a storage account in same or different subscription with PowerShell

I will try this  and yes this is very helpful , thankyou so much

Hi @Sandy, I hope this solution works for you and let me know if still need any help.
